# Mapping Over a Specific Axis in Scala

Tags: scala

If I have an `Array[Array[Double]]` in Scala, is there an idomatic way to map over the second axis?

For instance, consider the following matrix:

`val M : Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1d,2d),Array(3d,4d),Array(5d,6d))`

To normalize the rows I simply run:
`M.map(x=>x.map(_/x.sum))`

However, the normalize the columns it seems like I must execute:
`M.transpose.map(x=>x.map(_/x.sum)).transpose`

This is workable, but it becomes extremely tedious if I have more than two indices. In generally if I want to map over the last axis of a bunch of nested `Array`, i.e., `Array[Array[...Array[Double]...]]`, then I need to bubble the last axis to the front via map and transpose, then map over it, then bubble it back to the back.

Comment: why don't you use the breeze [library](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) that allows you to deal with all kind of matrix calculation?

Comment: @proximator in production I probably would, but with regards to the current question it doesn't give me any insight into the workings of Scala or functional programming tricks.